# How to split a column into multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

table1

```
Value (Always 3 Digit)

100x200x300
200x400x500
...
...
```

I want to make 3 column from value column

Expected Output

```
val1 val2 val3

100 200 300
200 400 500
...
...
```

Need Query Help

Comment: Are the values always three digits or can they vary? And do you want to do this once or ad hoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([VALUE],1,3) AS val1,
       SUBSTRING([VALUE],5,3) AS val2, 
       SUBSTRING([VALUE],9,3) AS val3
  FROM TABLE1
```

Answer (score 3):

This leverages [PARSENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) rather than SUBSTRING.

```
SELECT
   PARSENAME(Value2, 3) AS val1,
   PARSENAME(Value2, 2) AS val2,
   PARSENAME(Value2, 1) AS val3
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        REPLACE(Value, 'x', '.') AS Value2
    FROM
        MyTable
    ) T;
```

This code

- allows for different component value lengths
- assumes x is always the separator
- assumes always 3 components